# How to bind jetty to specific ip, allowing to access webapp from another computer?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty

I need to run local jetty server, which can provide access my web app from another computer in  another network. To be more specific to run jetty in computer A in network A, and reach app from Computer B in network B.

How can i do this using run jetty run eclipse plugin or mvn jetty:run command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for development purposes then either of those options should work, however if you are using it for any other purpose I would recommend running the stock jetty distribution configured appropriately or write a small embedded jetty server that does what you want to do.

you should be able to get to the appropriate documentation for your jetty version from here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe you now how i can do this with run jetty run plugin? I have tried adding `"--port=8888 --address=0.0.0.0 /"` to run configurations, but still I was unable to connect from another pc.

Comment: @Riku I use eclipse and the jetty server used by google app engine. "--address=0.0.0.0" works for me now. My McAfee firewall blocked port 8888.